# Ubuntu 16.04.2 Server keyboard layout selection fail

Tags: 16.04, server, keyboard-layout, kvm-virtualization

While setting up Ubuntu 16.04.2 Server via KVM and kimchi, i try to detect my keyboard layout (GER/DE). z key and w key getting recognized but when it tells to press 'ö',the key isn't identified.

If i pick the keyboard layout out of the list, some keys are wrong for example '-' is 'ß'.

Anyone got an idea how to fix this?

EDIT: It's a VNC Display by kimchi which i use.

Comment: Do you have a German physical keyboard? The layout should match the design of the keyboard.

Comment: Yes, it's a default german keyboard with T1 layout.

Comment: Can you please run the command `setxkbmap -query` and show us the output by editing your question.

Comment: I get: Cannot open display "default display"

Comment: Then you have a configuration issue which is over my head. Hopefully someone else can give you a hand.

Comment: I just found out that it's an VNC Display i use which i get by kimchi.

Answer (score 0):

Today I got the same problem -- changing the keyboard layout to English (USA) does the trick. The German Keyboard works now.